# JavaEE приложение. Правильная структура проекта

Tags: java, java-ee

Привет.Собираю проект через maven.
На данный момент у меня есть 4 модуля:

model - тут все entity лежат

dao- несколько dao классов

service - собственно сервисы

controller - тут контроллеры с post/get методами.

На данный момент контроллеры подгружают сервисы, сервисы - дао, дао подгружает model. На сколько я знаю, так в нормальной разработке не делают. Мне говорили что нужно вынести api и что-то еще куда-то. Как нормальные люди делают?

Comment: Правил и рекомендаций по построению иерархии пакетов не существует. В этом, как и в именовании, стоит ориентироваться на логику, удобство и чувство прекрасного. Не всегда получается даже у авторов стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: Просто не нужно делать множество классов, когда можно сделать 1 - не нужно делать класс ради одного метода и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно понимать что делает Ваше приложение, если это обычное CRUD приложение, тогда указанная Вами структура является наиболее часто употребляемой.

Если же приложение содержит серьезную логику или вы хотите ее отгородить от специфики WEB приложения, то есть в дальнейшем иметь возможность переносить ее на GUI или консольное приложение, тогда лучше подойти со стороны подхода Domain-Driven Design:
[image: DDD]
<sub>(источник: [8thlight.com](https://8thlight.com/blog/assets/posts/2012-08-13-the-clean-architecture/CleanArchitecture.jpg))</sub>

То есть определить смысловое ядро Вашего приложения и отделить его от WEB framework-а предоставив доступ к ядру только через интерфейсы.
Таким образом Ваша логика не будет зависеть ни от каких библиотек.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно архитектура серверного приложения так и выглядит.

Возможен вариант с добавлением модели для клиента в виде DTO ([Data Transfer Object](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/data-transfer-object.html)), для ограничения или расширения модели приложения.